# What is an ArchVisCharacter? What is it used for?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

As the question states.

I can't really find any useful documentation surrounding this.

What is an ArchVisCharacter and what do you use them for?

Comment: Did you try searching the term online? I did and the first result was a page from unreal's website. Did you try that?

Comment: @TomTsagk I spent around 15 minutes trying to find any information on what the actor does. I found nothing that explained its usage, so I asked here. I don't see this as a useless question for anyone in the community who may have the same question that I did either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AArchVisCharacter` is a character actor subclass](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Plugins/ArchVisCharacter/AArchVisCharacter/index.html). The term "ArchVis" is short for "architectural visualization," which is a feature area Unreal has been branching out into recently.

If you’re building any sort of architectural visualization or product design demo or VR scene [using Unreal Studio](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Studio/index.html), you may want to use an `AArchVisCharacter`. If you're just building a "regular game," you don't need to use it, although you probably could if you wanted to.

It's a reasonably small class contained in its own plugin. It provides some basic movement APIs suited for first-person style movement, and uses a related `UArchVisCharacterMovementComponent` to implement custom `PhysWalking` behavior.

Comment: That's incredibly interesting. I suppose this could almost be used as a sort of LOD for having far off walking characters visible, don't you think?

Comment: It doesn’t have anything to do with the graphics for the character, and it’s.m not materially different from other basic actors, and it’s by default set up to react to input like a FPS character... so I don’t think it has any particular utility in any sort of LOD scheme.